# Snap to a linestring

Tags: postgis, postgresql, snapping

I'm trying to create a line snapping tool in my Android app where I'm using the spatialite-android lib. I'm using the function `ST_Snap` where I want to snap a linestring with another linestring on the point where a line string is touching another one. here is the preview

[image]

Here is my gis query

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Snap(line, input, ST_Distance(input,line)*10.0)) 
FROM (SELECT 
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(88.4656805545 22.6896467287,88.4632558376 22.6896841575,88.4614285827 22.6882649519)',4326) As input, 
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(88.4654606134 22.690117835,88.4655571729 22.6896761149)',4326) As line);
```

But the above query snapping the line to the end. I'm guessing the query is not appropriate.

This is what happening

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ST_Snap`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html) will snap to an existing vertice. You would need to project your input endpoint to the line via [`ST_LineLocatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) to find the distance of the projected point from the start of the line. Then, using this distance, you need to find its coordinate via [`ST_LineInterpolatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html).
You would then create the snapped-line using the input start point and this found location.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_LineInterpolatePoint(line, 
                          ST_LineLocatePoint(line, 
                                             ST_EndPoint(input))))
FROM (SELECT 
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(88.4656805545 22.6896467287,88.4632558376 22.6896841575,88.4614285827 22.6882649519)',4326) As input, 
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(88.4654606134 22.690117835,88.4655571729 22.6896761149)',4326) As line) as foo;
```

Comment: In my case the blue line is actually the input and the green is the line i want snap.